# MVC + AutoMapper 7.0.1.0 - Is there a way to tell AutoMapper to ignore all of the properties except the ones which are mapped explicitly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, clr

We are using automapper to map complex object (nested objects with around 50~60 objects being mapped in a single profile). It worked in v4.2 When we upgraded to 7.0, it is throwing errors. We get an error "common language runtime detected an invalid program" when mapping. Is there a way we can tell AutoMapper to ignore all of the properties except those mapped explicitly and not specify each property individually.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Policy, PolicyDTO>().MaxDepth(3);
cfg.Advanced.AllowAdditiveTypeMapCreation = true;
```

Comment: You should try to isolate the problem. Otherwise there's little chance to understand why this occurs.

Comment: Any particular approach that needs to be followed? I have deleted all unused mappings manually, but still no luck

Comment: Start from the mapping that breaks, try to simplify it until it no longer breaks. Then you might have an idea about a repro.